# Slow starting of Java app after adding GC parameters

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection, wrapper

since i want to take data from the GC of the JVM the following parameters were added in the custom_wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.java.additional.306=-Xlog:gc:utctime
wrapper.java.additional.307=-verbose:gc
wrapper.java.additional.308=-Xlog:gc*
wrapper.java.additional.309=-Xloggc:/opt/java/logs/gc-%t.log
wrapper.java.additional.310=-Xlog::::filecount=5,filesize=2M
```

After adding those parameters the application is starting dramatically slow - around 20mins.
Before those paramaters normal start was around 2 mins.

Do i made some mistakes with adding the parameters or this is a normal behavior?

Comment: How big are the log files, and how fast is the storage device that these logs are written to?

Comment: log files are 2mb and the storage is a corporate so it is really quick

Comment: Why don't you look with a profiler at what the process is doing during these 20 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean with “the storage is a corporate”? The only meaning of the word “corporate” I know of, is about ownership and that doesn’t say anything about the speed of the device. And, of course, the log files are only 2MB, because you told the JVM to split the logs into 2MB chunks. So the actual question would be, how many of them are created during startup.